# Implementing player movement with setInterval

Tags: javascript, game-engine, 2d-games, pixi.js, topdown

**If you close-vote or down-vote the question please comment why. I'm willing to change it, but I can only do this if you tell me what is wrong.**

I'm currently trying to implement the player movement for a bomberman-like game that I'm writing. The layout is very similar to this one:
[image]

**Movement direction priorities**
Basically, when you press one of the arrow keys, the player should start moving into that direction until he hits a block. (This already works)

But it's more complex. For instance, when you hold `left` and then also `up`, the player should move `up` until he hits a block, then he should try to go `left` until he can go `up` again or hits a block.

So the last key always has the highest priority and the one before has the second most priority and so on. (I have written the code to keep track of the priorities, but it wouldn't work because of the following problem.)

**Floating point position**

The player doesn't simply move from field (0|0) to field (0|1). The player has a fixed speed configured in a variable (default 1 field per second) and his position will get updated every ~10 milliseconds. Lags could cause the position update to be delayed by multiple seconds.

So the position is almost never an integer and almost always a float.

**Collision problem**

The player has the exact same width and height as every other element in the game. 
This means, in order to get from (0|2.0001312033) to (1|2), you first have to get to exactly (0|2) so that the player doesn't collide with the blocks on (1|1) and (1|3) and only then you can actually go through to reach (1|2).

The problem is that the player almost never actually reaches such an ideal integer position because the position is only updated every ~10 milliseconds.

**Field skipping**

Another obvious problem is that the player might skip a field if a lag causes the position update to be delayed by a second, causing the player to jump over walls, items and explosions.

---

**Summary**
If the player moved by more than one field since the last position update, he will skip a field and walking around a corner is virtually impossible because the player has to be perfectly positioned in order to not collide with any blocks when taking the turn.

I just can't think of a good way to fix these problems without creating massive amounts unreadable code. I would really like to keep it clean and be able to understand the code when I look at it again in the future.

Is there maybe a game movement library that could help? Any other ideas?

**My code fo far**

These are the key parts of my current code. I tried to remove all the irrelevant parts.

```
"use strict";
class Player {
    constructor(gameField, pos) { // gameField is an object containing lots of methods and properties like the game field size and colision detection fucntions
        // this._accuratePos is the floating point position
        this._accuratePos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pos));
        // this.pos is the integer posision 
        this.pos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pos));
        // this.moveSpeed is the movement speed of the player
        this.moveSpeed = 3;
        // this.activeMoveActions will contain the currently pressed arrow keys, sorted by priority. (last pressed, highest prio)
        this.activeMoveActions = []
        // this.moveInterval will contain an interval responsible for updating the player position
        this.moveInterval;
    }

    // directionKey can be 'up', 'down', 'left' or 'right'
    // newState can be true if the key is pressed down or false if it has been released.
    moveAction(directionKey, newState=true) { // called when a key is pressed or released. e.g. moveAction('left', false) // left key released
        if (this.activeMoveActions.includes(directionKey)) // remove the key from the activeMoveActions array
            this.activeMoveActions = this.activeMoveActions.filter(current => current !== directionKey);
        if (newState) // if the key was pressed down
            this.activeMoveActions.unshift(directionKey); // push it to the first position of the array

        if (this.activeMoveActions.length === 0) { // if no direction key is pressed
            if (this.moveInterval) { // if there still is a moveInterval
                clearInterval(this.moveInterval); // remove the moveInterval
            return; // exit the function
        }

        let lastMoveTime = Date.now(); // store the current millisecond time in lastMoveTime
        let lastAccPos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.accuratePos)); // store a copy of this.accuratePos in lastAccPos

        this.moveInterval = setInterval(()=>{
            let now = Date.now(); // current time in milliseconds
            let timePassed = now-lastMoveTime; // time passed since the last interval iteration in milliseconds
            let speed = (this.moveSpeed*1)/1000; // the movement speed in fields per millisecond
            let maxDistanceMoved = timePassed*speed; // the maximum distance the player could have moved (limited by hitting a wall etc)
            // TODO: check if distance moved > 1 and if so check if user palyer went through blocks

            let direction = this.activeMoveActions[0]; // highest priority direction
            // this.activeMoveActions[1] would contain the second highest priority direction if this.activeMoveActions.length > 1

            let newAccPos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lastAccPos)); // store a copy of lastAccPos in newAccPos
            // (newAccPos will not necessarily become the new player posision. only if it's a valid position.)
            if (direction === 'up') { // if the player pressed the arrow up key
                newAccPos.y -= maxDistanceMoved; // subtract the maxDistanceMoved from newAccPos.y 
            } else if (direction === 'down') {
                newAccPos.y += maxDistanceMoved;
            } else if (direction === 'left') {
                newAccPos.x -= maxDistanceMoved;
            } else if (direction === 'right') {
                newAccPos.x += maxDistanceMoved;
            }

            // if it is possible to move the plyer to the new position in stored in newAccPos 
            if (!this.gameField.posIntersectsMoveBlockingElement(newAccPos) && this.gameField.posIsOnField(newAccPos)) {
                this.accuratePos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newAccPos)); // set the new player position to a copy of the modified newAccPos
            } else { // if the newly calculated position is not a possible position for the player
                this.accuratePos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.pos)); // overwrite the players accurate position with a copy of the last rounded position
            }

            realityCheck(); // handle colliding items and explosions
            lastMoveTime = now; // store the time recorded in the beginning of the interval function
            lastAccPos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newAccPos)); // store a copy of the new position in lastAccPos
        }, 10); // run this function every 10 milliseconds
    }
    set accuratePos(newAccPos) {
        let newPos = { // convert to rounded position
            x: Math.round(newAccPos.x),
            y: Math.round(newAccPos.y)
        };
        if (this.gameField.posIsOnField(newPos)) { // if the posision is on the game field
            this._accuratePos = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newAccPos));
            this.pos = newPos; 
        }
    }
    get accuratePos() {
        return this._accuratePos;
    }
    realityCheck() { 
        // ignore this method, it simply checks if the current position collides with an items or an explosion
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `setinterval` for movement its unreliable and not in sync with keypresses. Each `keypress` should trigger an event, even when held down. All you need is respond to each `keypress` event

Comment: Yeah, but holding down a key should constantly move the player. There is no way around an interval.

Comment: No, when holding down a key it triggers the keypress event over and over so by using that event you only need to worry about responding to a single keypress event. Check keyCode and move accordingly.

Comment: But not at a constant rate. Please note that I'm implementing this on the server side. It would be extremely wasteful to spam key down events to the server when you could simply send one key down event instead.

Comment: you need to validate the commands on the server and if the command is valid, i.e: User didn't move from one end of the map to the other or shoot through a wall then the command is valid and you execute it. At this point it doesn't matter who or what send the command. Preventing "hacking" is done through separate means, such as client installations detecting certain types of third party programs or validate that some client dlls have been messed with and auto block them from joining the server.

Comment: As I said, the player has to move at a constant speed. It should not be possible to move faster by pressing the button repeatedly. And since the server runs locally, latency isn't really a concern.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162611/discussion-between-forivin-and-nope).

Comment: Track the state of the buttons and update the player position during your simulation's update step. In order to track the button state, just record changes to that state.

Comment: @Forivin If you want to make movement a constant speed then the `keydown` and `keyup` could simply turn on/off movement and change direction as needed, you decide the speed. Move when key is down and don't move when not down. So if someone sends 1000 keypresses per second they simply turn movement on/off.

Comment: @dtanders I already track the button states. When they change, the `moveAction` method is called accordingly. What do you mean by `simulation's update step`? If you mean my setInterval function: I'm already doing this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to put proper architecture for your game in place, and simply attack problems one by one.

First and most important: introduce the game loop http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html. Do not issue any "setIntervals" inside your game code. For every frame in your game do the following:

- Read the controller state
- Issue command to underlying game object
- Call update(timeMillis) on all game objects to execute the commands

As part of game loop implementation you may want to address "lag by a second" problem. For example, by setting minimum timeMillis to 100ms (i.e. if game is lower than 10 FPS, the gameplay itself will slow down). There are many other options, just read up on various game loop approaches.

Then attack the Controller implementation. Implement separate well defined controller object, probably something like (TypeScript):

```
class Controller {
  public update(timeMillis: number);
  public getPrimaryDirection(): Vector;
  public getSecondaryDirection(): Vector;
}
```

Test it out inside the game loop with console.log, then set it aside.

Then focus on LevelGrid object and your collision problem. There are A LOT OF ways to address the issues you mention with collision and navigation. Here are a few pointers on possible solutions:

- Simple "fixed size steps" approach. Choose small fixed size delta (e.g. 0.1 pixel or 1 pixel). Inside your game loop make a sub-loop, which will move player by fixed step into the right direction, while LevelGrid.canMoveTo(x, y, w, h) returns true. Subtract time it takes to go by 0.1 pixels from remainingTimeDelta. When remainingTimeDelta is below zero, exit subloop. Properly check for "epsilon" distance when implementing LevelGrid.canMoveTo, so that floating point inprecision does not hurt you.
- "Physics casting" approach. Make LevelGrid.castRectangle(x, y, w, h, dx, dy) function. It will compute the following: if rect with the given size move in the given direction, where exactly will it hit the first wall? You can find implementation in many physics libraries or game engines.

I suggest you consider choosing good JS game engine, which will provide the architecture for you.

Comment: I can't just make the game run slower. It's a multiplayer game and the code I provided runs on the server. Also, I decided to only draw frames when there were any changes, otherwise I would be wasting a lot of resources. Since my game is a multiplayer game, my game logic runs on the node.js server. On the client side I'm using pixi.js to render everything. The game libraries that I could find were expected to be used on the client side only, thus I can't use them.

Comment: 1) Fixed size steps will work just fine on the server in a game loop. PIXI client will just render whatever it can catch up with on its own pace, doing interpolations as necessary. 2) I definitely suggest you do not worry about _any_ optimization at this step. Just redraw the screen 60 times per second in requestAnimationFrame. As you add animations to the game screen will be changed pretty much every frame anyway.

Comment: Ah - and one more thing. Experiment a bit more with the movements in the original games (like Dyna Blaster). What they do is "round" your vertical position to the central line, if you are within the given threshold (for example, 20 pixels), press press horisontal movement button and there's no wall in the given direction. This resolves all problems with accuracy indeed.

Answer (score 1):

## Using linked map cells.

Like linked lists, linked maps make navigating complex mazes easy.

The problems of wall collision (including wall skipping) and all the others you list are non issues as they simply never occur.

### The cell.

First you define each map cell to hold a position of the cell, `x`, `y`.

For each free cell, one the player may occupy, that cell holds a reference to the cells that the player can move to by name, left, right, up, down.

Thus a cell may look like

```
cell = {
    x,y, // the cell pos
    left : null, // left is blocked
    right : cell, // a cell to the right that can be moved to 
    up    : cell, // a cell above that can be moved to 
    down  : cell, // a cell below that can be moved to 
}
```

A cell to the left must also point to the cell on the right. Thus `cell.left.right === cell`   . Or two steps left and back `cell.left.left.right.right === cell`

### The player

The player holds the cell that is under it (always starts directly over a cell) `player.cell = ?`

It is easy to check if the player can move in a direction. Say the left control is pressed, just check `if(keyboard.left && player.cell.left) { //can move left`. And the position to move is stored in the cell

As you do not want a player to instantly move to the next cell, so you save that cell and using a counter start moving to the new cell. The counter values from 0 to 1, with 0 being at the current cell and 1 at the next.

When the count reaches 1, then set the cell under the player to that next cell, and set the counter to 0, and repeat the process. Check input, then check cell for cell in that direction, move if so.

If the player reverses direction, just reduce the counter until back to zero.

### Prioritize movement directions

By keeping track of the last direction moved you can use an array to prioritize the next movements.

```
const checkMoveOrder = {
   left : ["up","down","right","left"],
   right : ["up","down","left","right"],
   up : ["left","right","down","up"],
   down : ["left","right","up","down"],
}
```

So if the players last move was left then at the next cell the keys are checked in order  up, down, right, left. the player will always turn if a side direction key is down.

### Many more benefits.

- Completely eliminates the need of player map collision testing.
- Solves the problem of player alignment as you ensure that you always have an aligned cell and the distance you have moved from it
- Makes projecting player position forward in time very easy. Just follow the cells from the cell under the player.
- As well as player movement it helps with non player characters as well, greatly simplifying path finding solutions.
- You can use fixed time steps or random time steps, as long as you step only from cell to cell.
- The player can never get stuck as you can not move to a location that has not way out.